# println not printing to console (HKSampleQuery)

Tags: swift

1) Why do I not get any output in the console with the println function ?
(I dont get any errors when I run the code.)

```
func perfromQueryForHRSamples() {
    let startDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*60*60)
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let heartRateSample = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: .None)

    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate),
        predicate: predicate,
        limit: 100,
        sortDescriptors: nil,
        resultsHandler: { (query, results, error) in

            if error != nil {
                println("There was an error: \(error)")

            }

            for result in results as [HKQuantitySample]! {
                let count = results.count
                println("Success \(count)")
            }
    })

    self.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)

}
```

Comment: Because `results` is an empty array? You are searching for samples between now and now. I guess there aren't that many. Or maybe `healthStore` is nil. Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  You are probably right, but I thought the whole reason for the if error != nil was there to tell me if something went wrong?

Comment: But it's not an error if the method returns an empty array. It just means that no samples could be found. You should log the size of the array to console. As I said, your problem is probably that your predicate limits the samples to those that happen at the exact same moment the code is run. Set startDate to `NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*60*60)` (30 days in the past) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried your suggestion and updated the code in the question. I also tried to count the result array, but still I get nothing.  Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Because the function was not called in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    requestAuthorisationForHealthStore()
    perfromQueryForHRSamples()
}
```